# InputMismatchException for String input into integer field

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, inputmismatchexception

I am having trouble with entering non-integers into an integer field. I am only taking precautions so that if another person uses/works on my program they don't get this `InputMismatchException`.

When I enter a non-digit character into the `input` variable, I get the above error. Is there any way to compensate for this like one could do for a `NullPointerException` when it comes to strings?

This code is redacted just to include the relevant portions causing the problem.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

   int input = 0;   

   System.out.println("What is your age? : ");
   input = user_input.nextInt();
   System.out.println("You are: " +input+ " years old");

  }

}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt%28%29

Comment: To expand on JB Nizet's comment a bit:  When working with Java, the documentation is your friend.  Always look there first.  The [documentation for Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) can tell you a lot about how to use it.

Comment: @Yiuri what do you really want? You want to prevent an inputmismatchException from occurring is it?

Comment: Thx for your help everyone! Used the user_input.hasNextInt() method. with the if else statement provided by dizzicode and others.  Works to perfection now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an if statement to check if user_input `hasNextInt()`. If the input is an integer, then set `input` equal to `user_input.nextInt()`. Otherwise, display a message stating that the input is invalid. This should prevent exceptions.

```
System.out.println("What is your age? : ");
if(user_input.hasNextInt()) {
    input = user_input.nextInt();
}
else {
    System.out.println("That is not an integer.");
}
```

Here is some more information about `hasNextInt()` from [Javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt()).

On a side note, variable names in Java should follow the `lowerMixedCase` convention. For example, `user_input` should be changed to `userInput`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a try-catch block. You need to use this if you want to be sure of not making the program-flow stop.

```
try { 
  input = user_input.nextInt();
}
catch (InputMismatchException exception) { //here you can catch that exception, so program will not stop
  System.out.println("Integers only, please."); //this is a comment
  scanner.nextLine(); //gives a possibility to try giving an input again
}
```

Comment: An explanation of why you recommend this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [`try-catch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html) block:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MyWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {

   Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

   int input = 0;   

   System.out.println("What is your age? : ");

   try{
       input = user_input.nextInt();
   }catch(InputMisMatchException ex)
       System.out.println("An error ocurred");
   }

   System.out.println("You are: " +input+ " years old");

  }
}
```

If you want to provide the user to enter another `int` you can create a boolean variable and make a `do-while` loop to repeat it. As follows:

```
boolean end = false;

//code

do
{
   try{
       input = user_input.nextInt();
       end = true;
   }catch(InputMisMatchException ex)
       System.out.println("An error ocurred");
       end = false;
       System.out.println("Try again");
       input.nextLine();
   }
}while(end == false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Test using `hasNextInt()`.

```
Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("What is your age?");
if (user_input.hasNextInt()) {
    int input = user_input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("You are " + input + " years old");
} else {
    System.out.println("You are a baby");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `Scanner's next()` method to get data instead of using nextInt(). Then parse it to integer using `int input = Integer.parseInt(inputString);`
parseInt() method throws `NumberFormatException` if it is not int, which you can handle accordingly.